# Sequence of 3 node fetch POST calls fails unless combining await and then

Tags: node.js, async-await, fetch

In a javascript I run the below 3 fetch POST requests:

**test.js**

```
fetch(endpoint, {
  method: "POST",
  headers: {
    Authorization: "Bearer " + token,
    "Content-Type": "application/json-patch+json",
    "accept": "application/json"  
  },
  body: b1
})
 .then((response) => {
  console.log(response.status)
  return response.json()
})
.then(data => {
  console.log(data);
})
.catch(error => {
  console.error('CREATE Error:', error);
});


fetch(endpoint, {
  method: "POST",
  headers: {
    Authorization: "Bearer " + token,
    "Content-Type": "application/json-patch+json",
    "accept": "application/json"  
  },
  body: b2
})
 .then((response) => {
  console.log(response.status)
  return response.json()
})
.then(data => {
  console.log(data);
})
.catch(error => {
  console.error('CREATE Error:', error);
});


fetch(endpoint, {
  method: "POST",
  headers: {
    Authorization: "Bearer " + token,
    "Content-Type": "application/json-patch+json",
    "accept": "application/json"  
  },
  body: b3
})
 .then((response) => {
  console.log(response.status)
  return response.json()
})
.then(data => {
  console.log(data);
})
.catch(error => {
  console.error('CREATE Error:', error);
});
```

but it randomly fails with one or two of the requests e.g.:

```
❯ node test.js
500
{
  type: 'https://httpstatuses.com/500',
  title: 'Internal Server Error',
  status: 500,
  detail: ''
}
500
{
  type: 'https://httpstatuses.com/500',
  title: 'Internal Server Error',
  status: 500,
  detail: ''
}
200
{
  status: 'succesful!'
}
```

But if I add an `await` to each `fetch`:

```
await fetch(endpoint, {
  method: "POST",
  headers: {
    Authorization: "Bearer " + token,
    "Content-Type": "application/json-patch+json",
    "accept": "application/json"  
  },
  body: b1
})
 .then((response) => {
  console.log(response.status)
  return response.json()
})
.then(data => {
  console.log(data);
})
.catch(error => {
  console.error('CREATE Error:', error);
});


await fetch(endpoint, {
  method: "POST",
  headers: {
    Authorization: "Bearer " + token,
    "Content-Type": "application/json-patch+json",
    "accept": "application/json"  
  },
  body: b2
})
 .then((response) => {
  console.log(response.status)
  return response.json()
})
.then(data => {
  console.log(data);
})
.catch(error => {
  console.error('CREATE Error:', error);
});


await fetch(endpoint, {
  method: "POST",
  headers: {
    Authorization: "Bearer " + token,
    "Content-Type": "application/json-patch+json",
    "accept": "application/json"  
  },
  body: b3
})
 .then((response) => {
  console.log(response.status)
  return response.json()
})
.then(data => {
  console.log(data);
})
.catch(error => {
  console.error('CREATE Error:', error);
});
```

it always works - all 3 get successfully posted:

```
❯ node test.js
200
{
  status: 'succesful!'
}
200
{
  status: 'succesful!'
}
200
{
  status: 'succesful!'
}
```

From what I understand you *can* combine `await` and `then` but generally you either select either the `await` approach or the `then` approach.

So what am I doing wrong in the above example?

How do I make all these 3 post request complete successfully each time
with using only `then`?

Then I will deal with the doing it using just `await` only or `Promise.all`:
https://vanillajstoolkit.com/reference/ajax/multiple-endpoints/

as a follow up exercise unless I of course need to use them combined with `then`.

**UPDATE**: And the example with curl that always works (probably because curl is synchronous/internally does waiting correctly):

```
bodies.forEach(body => {
  const cmd = `curl -si -X POST -H 'accept: application/json' \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/json-patch+json' \
  -H "Authorization: Bearer ${token}" \
  -d '${body}' '${endpoint}'`
  
  const execSync = child.execSync;
  const result = execSync(cmd, { encoding: "utf-8" });
  console.log(result)
})
```

when executed:

```
❯ node test_curl.js
HTTP/2 200
...

HTTP/2 200
...

HTTP/2 200
...
```

But "forcing" async invocations with curl based on this example:
https://serverfault.com/a/1084693/138328

gives same unpredictable/random failing behaviour as when using fetch/then

Comment: Is it possible that the target site simply times out or refuses your request if you send 3 requests at once?

Comment: Thats also my guess but if I do the same with plain curl  - sending all 3 in a loop  - it works fine + it works if I do the above where I combine `await` with `then`. Just NOT when only using `then`

Comment: Can you edit your question with your cURL try? Maybe that's synchronous?

Comment: Updated the post with curl example and yes I think that synchronous.

Comment: Can you test sending the cURL requests asynchronously? (https://serverfault.com/questions/1083967/curl-command-send-asynchronous-request) Is the behavior reproducing then?

Comment: Ha that gives the same behavior/error/random failure based on the example from https://serverfault.com/a/1084693/138328 . So the backend I am calling does not support async requests or - and if so is that a well know thing/limitation?

Comment: It's just something some servers do. There are cases when some users try to brute-force passwords or to artificially overload with denial of service attacks. Against these some servers are protecting themselves by not serving the request of an IP address if one was already sent and is being processed, or so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the comment-section of the question we have reached the conclusion that the server does not serve too frequent requests or on-going requests.

This was experimentally verified via sending async cURL requests and the problem reproduced even then, which proves that the issue is not due to the `fetch` call per se, but to the asynchronous nature of parallelly sent requests.

Comment: Out of curiosity why is it that sending 3 request synchronously is seen as OK while sending the same 3 messages asynchronously is seen as  "malicious" (e.g any links to resources documenting this or how to configure it on a server/waf)? Also my original question was actually regarding why I have to to use both `await` and `then`to make it work (from what I have read is generally not recommended to combine the two).

Comment: @u123 depends on the server and on how it is being set up and programmed. For example, nginx has rate limiting, which is limiting the number of requests a user may send, so maximum 1 request will be processed per user at each 100 milliseconds or so.

Comment: Yes I was expecting to see a 429 rate limit code but just got a 500 - which is probably just the general error this particular error this server sends. Just curious to find more official resources on the subject: why async request has a higher chance of getting refused compared to sync requests.

Comment: @u123 because they contribute to server load increase and it might fail to server capacity limits or defense against denial of service attacks.